# Sorting directory files by creation date in php

Tags: php, sorting

Here is the code I use to get an array of the files in a directory.

```
$dir = "thumbnails/";
$images = scandir($dir);
```

How can I sort the $images array by creation date?  I found a couple of ways but I couldn't get any of them to work with my array.

Thanks,

Comment: Why don't you post what you tried?

Comment: array_multisort(array_map('filemtime', $images), SORT_DESC, $images);

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you can get the creation time of the file with [`filectime()`](http://php.net/filectime). Just put it in an array with the filename and sort the array.

Creation time is not stored on most *nix filesystems.

Comment: its a ftp server running linux.

Answer (score 0):

try the following tutorial that includes a script on how to sort by file modification/creation.

http://www.bitrepository.com/sort-files-by-filemtime.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to sort manually

```
$dir = "thumbnails/";

function compare_time($a, $b)
{
    global $dir;

    $timeA = filectime("$dir/$a");
    $timeB = filectime("$dir/$b");

    if($timeA == $timeB) return 0;

    return ($timeA < $timeB) ? -1 : 1;
}

$images = scandir($dir);
usort($images, 'compare_time');
```

Comment: On unix system you should use filemtime instead of filectime.

Comment: how would I access each of the items in this array?

Comment: it's simply an int indexed array of file names. something like

Array([0] => '.', [1] => '..', [2] => 'afile.jpg');

have a look at [php.net/scandir](http://php.net/scandir)